# Why is text pushed down after a float: left block?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a structure of an image that's floated to the left and another block that should follow it horizontally to the right. It does, except for when the length of the text of that block gets bigger. Then stuff gets messy.

Here's my structure:

```css
post-big-then-small-2-smaller {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
    
.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .post-thumbnail img {
  height: 90px;
  width: 40%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
    
    .post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-title {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}

.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-title a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
    
.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-meta .entry-date-published {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<article class="post-big-then-small-2-smaller">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://www.marrakech-desert-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Morocco-sahara-desert-tour-Marrakech-to-Merzouga-3-days.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <header class="entry-header">
          <div class="entry-meta">
              <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">Finmus Maximus</a></h3>
              <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">
                  <time class="entry-date-published" datetime="2017-07-02T07:31:04+00:00">July 2, 2017</time>
              </a>
      </header>
  </article>
```

What I am experiencing:

[image]

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: _"Any ideas as to why?"_ - because you explicitly specified that this should happen ...? `.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-title a {
    white-space: nowrap; ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid applying CSS styling to child elements, instead, apply the CSS styling to `.post-thumbnail` & `.entry-header`. Also remove `white-space: nowrap` from the title (it has no use).

> In your case apply CSS properties (float, height, etc.) to `.post-thumbnail` instead of `.post-thumbnail img`

Example:

```
.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .post-thumbnail {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.post-big-then-small-2-smaller {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .post-thumbnail {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .post-thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-title {
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}
.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-title a {
    color: #1e1e1e;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-meta .entry-date-published {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<article class="post-big-then-small-2-smaller">
      <div class="post-thumbnail">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://www.marrakech-desert-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Morocco-sahara-desert-tour-Marrakech-to-Merzouga-3-days.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <header class="entry-header">
          <div class="entry-meta">
              <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus Finmus Maximus</a></h3>
              <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">
                  <time class="entry-date-published" datetime="2017-07-02T07:31:04+00:00">July 2, 2017</time>
              </a>
      </header>
  </article>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works, but what did we do here? What am I missing? I feel as if I fixed this issue 50 times before, but never learned what's causing it.

Comment: @DanielMoss You are applying CSS styles to image which is inside `.post-thumbnail` and the title which is inside `.entry-title` doesn't know that `img` is floated left. Therefore you should assign CSS property to `.post-thumbnail` instead of `img`, so that `.entry-title` should know where to wrap around. I hope you get it? See the example in my answer I've written.

Comment: @DanielMoss If this answer helped you out, Please don't forget to upvote & accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [display property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) specifies the type of box used for an HTML element. for your case you can use display:`inline-block` :

```
 .post-thumbnail {
width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
 header.entry-header {
width: 50%;
float: right;
text-align: left;
}
```

> Displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box

then you set where the inside element you want to float :

```css
post-big-then-small-2-smaller {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 24px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }
    
.post-big-then-small-2-smaller .post-thumbnail img {
    height: 90px;
    width: 40%;
    object-fit: cover;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
    
    .post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-title {
        margin: 0 0 6px 0;
    }
    .post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-title a {
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: #1e1e1e;
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .post-big-then-small-2-smaller .entry-header .entry-meta .entry-date-published {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #3a3a3a;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
article.post-big-then-small-2-smaller {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.post-thumbnail {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
header.entry-header {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
.text{width:100%;display:inline-block;max-width:75%;margin:auto}
```

```html
<article class="post-big-then-small-2-smaller">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://www.marrakech-desert-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Morocco-sahara-desert-tour-Marrakech-to-Merzouga-3-days.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <div class="entry-meta">
                            <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">Finmus Maximus</a></h3>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">
                                <time class="entry-date-published" datetime="2017-07-02T07:31:04+00:00">July 2, 2017</time>
                            </a>
                </div>
</header>
<div class="text"><p>text text text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text</p></div>
  </article>
<article class="post-big-then-small-2-smaller">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://www.marrakech-desert-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Morocco-sahara-desert-tour-Marrakech-to-Merzouga-3-days.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <div class="entry-meta">
                            <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">Finmus Maximus</a></h3>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">
                                <time class="entry-date-published" datetime="2017-07-02T07:31:04+00:00">July 2, 2017</time>
                            </a>
                </div>
</header>
<div class="text"><p>text text text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text</p></div>
  </article>
<article class="post-big-then-small-2-smaller">
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="https://www.marrakech-desert-trips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Morocco-sahara-desert-tour-Marrakech-to-Merzouga-3-days.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <div class="entry-meta">
                            <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">Finmus Maximus</a></h3>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="bookmark">
                                <time class="entry-date-published" datetime="2017-07-02T07:31:04+00:00">July 2, 2017</time>
                            </a>
                </div>
</header>
<div class="text"><p>text text text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text</p></div>
  </article>
```